# Gluing morphisms of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ over complex numbers. Let $T^*M$ be co-tangent bundle of $M$ with transition functions $\{g_{ij}\}$ on an affine cover $\{U_i\}$ of $M$. Suppose there are morphisms $\phi_i :T^*M_{\mid_{U_i}} \to \mathbb{C}^n$.
If $\phi_j \circ g_{ij} = \phi_i$, then one can glue $\phi_i$ to get a map $\phi : T^*M \to \mathbb{C}^n$.

Question: How to interpriate the existence of such maps $\phi_i$ satisfying  $\phi_j \circ g_{ij} = \phi_i$, in terms of vanishing of some cohomolgy group?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The $g_{ij}$ are functions on $M$, the $\phi_i$ on $T^*M$, how do you compose them?

Comment: Here we consider $T^*M$ is obtained by gluing $U_i \times \mathbb{C}^n$ by the functions $g_{ij}$, i.e., the gluing data for $T^*M$ is $(U_i \times \mathbb{C}^n, U_{ij} \times C^n, g_{ij})$.  Then a morphism $f: T^*M \to Y$ can be represented by $(f_i: U_i \times \mathbb{C}^n \to Y |f_j \circ g_{ij} = f_i)$.